# Google maps play service library add error

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

Hi This is something am confused ,when am adding the library,browser shows which can find the path the of play services library.but code shows an error.well thats not the matter,when i checked again in library where shows play services cant find the library.am including the images that of issue.please find me ,why it happens

[image]

Comment: Yes this happens sometimes in my case also.Do you import google play service library into your workspace?If it is,then delete that from your workspace,again import it and then add that library.In my case it always works.

Answer (score 1):

It justs happened me to. Delete lib, clean project. I physically erased the folders and the .metadata folder, then it worked. Hope it helps